# How can I use Linq to detect duplicates in nested object structure

Tags: c#, duplicates

I am working with the following JSON payload and I would like to detect duplicates inside each item inside the root array but at the "**categoryType**" level and detect duplicates at the "types.**type**" level as well within each rootCollection array item.

Essentially I don't want to have multiple root array items with the same categoryType - as you can see I have 2 x elements with value "Temporary" but I would like to only have a single array item inside the rootCollection with categoryType "Temporary".

Also within each root array item I don't want to have multiple array items within the "types" array with the same "type" value.
I hope I am making sense.

Here is example payload:

```
{
  "rootCollection": 
  [
    {
      "category": {
        "categoryType": {
          "value": "Temporary"
        }
      },
      "types": [
        {
          "type": {
            "value": "option1"
          },
          "subTypes": [
            {
              "subType": {
                "value": "optionA"
              }
            },
            {
              "subType": {
                "value": "optionB"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": {
            "value": "option1"
          },
          "subTypes": [
            {
              "subType": {
                "value": "optionA"
              }
            },
            {
              "subType": {
                "value": "optionB"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": {
        "categoryType": {
          "value": "Temporary"
        }
      },
      "types": [
        {
          "type": {
            "value": "option1"
          },
          "subTypes": [
            {
              "subType": {
                "value": "optionA"
              }
            },
            {
              "subType": {
                "value": "optionB"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": {
            "value": "option1"
          },
          "subTypes": [
            {
              "subType": {
                "value": "optionA"
              }
            },
            {
              "subType": {
                "value": "optionB"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am receiving this payload via an API call and I have deserialized this to C# object.

How could I go about detecting duplicates using linq in C#?
I don't have control over categoryType and type.value level.

So far I have done this using GroupBy on the Category.CategoryType but I can't seem to work how to detect duplicates within the types array within each rootCollection array item.

I have only got this so far:

`var duplicateCategories = rootCollection.GroupBy(x => x.Category.CategoryType.Value).Any(g => g.Count() > 1);`

Answer (score 0):

```
var filteredCollection = rootObject.RootCollection
    .GroupBy(item => item.Category.CategoryType.Value)
    .Select(group =>
    {
        var firstItem = group.First();
        firstItem.Types = firstItem.Types
            .GroupBy(type => type.Type.Value)
            .Select(typeGroup => typeGroup.First())
            .ToList();
        return firstItem;
    })
    .ToList();
```

group your root collection by `categoryType` and select the first item from each group. Then, for each item, group its `types` by `type.Value` and select the first from each subgroup to remove duplicates at both levels

Comment: I appreciate your response, but this is only returning the first record in rootCollection array when I tried it.

What if i don't want to remove them but report the count of duplicates? How could I achieve this?